# JQuery Hammer can not listen to swipe on mac?

Tags: jquery, swipe, multi-touch, hammer.js

I try to use JQuery Hammer to listen to the swipe gesture on mac (laptop), but it doesn't work.

[Code]:

```
var hammer_options = {swipe: true, swipe_max_touches: 1, swipe_velocity: 0.2};
$(document).hammer(hammer_options).on("swipe", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(event.gesture.touches.length); 

});
```

Use this code, when one finger swipe on browser page, nothing happens. JQuery hammer can not listen to swipe gesture on mac(laptop)?

---

My final goal is to detecting four fingers swipe on browser page
I think the [Code] should be like this, is it correct?

```
var hammer_options = {swipe: true, swipe_max_touches: 0, swipe_velocity: 0.2};
$(document).hammer(hammer_options).on("swipe", function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.gesture.touches.length >= 4) alert("GET IT.");
});
```

Comment: Please use the console to debug (`console.log(event.gesture.touches.length`) and not `alert`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't work. Is something wrong with my code?